# Three.js getting the parent object (a group) from it's children

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

In my scene, there are many object groups (Object3Ds), and I have setup a system for clicking / hovering over them to do certain things. When it uses the raycaster to find which objects are under the mouse, it returns the individual object, not the group (which I need).

The code I used to get the objects under the cursor looks like so:

```
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
clickobjstore = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);

// The following doesn't work because intersects[0] is not the group, it's the object within the group!
for (j = 0; j < intersects[0].object.children.length; j++) {
    intersects[0].object.children[j].material.color.setHex(0x1A75FF);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Object3D class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D) stores a reference to the `parent`-Object for you:

`var objectGroup = intersects[0].parent;`

```
for (j = 0; j < objectGroup.children.length; j++) {
    objectGroup.children[j].material.color.setHex(0x1A75FF);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've guessed since it's this simple :)